# Is there a Notification when CoreData finished reading data from disk?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I have a Mac (not document) app, that uses CoreData.

When launching the app, it reads the data stored on the filesystem.

I have to setup some things in *-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching* based on the information stored using CoreData.

So it would be nice to know when my app read everything from disk.

If I do my setup in *-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching* i doesn't work. If I do it a few seconds later it works!

Thx!

Comment: What's doing the unarchiving? Are you using object controllers?

Comment: unarchives was probably the wrong word. I replaced it with "reads". Yes I use ArrayControllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using object controllers that automatically prepare their own content, you can observe `arrangedObjects` to find out when they have fetched their content. This does not guarantee that the actual objects are not faults. In fact, that's one of the main strengths of Core Data: objects are lazily loaded from disk.

If you for some reason want to make sure that most disk activity has taken place in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, you can perform a custom fetch that specifically does not return objects as faults. Look up "prefetching" in the Core Data documentation. However, there is no guarantee that Core Data won't fault these objects at a later time due to memory constraints, thereby incurring another disk read when those objects are loaded again.

You can of course also use the `NSBinaryStoreType`, in which case the entire store is loaded into memory synchronously when it is added to the persistent store coordinator.

Comment: Thank you so far! I am trying to observe arrangedObjects this way: `[myArrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL]; ` and `- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context
{
        NSLog(@"test");
}` 
However the method doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `myArrayController` non-nil when you call `addObserver`?

Comment: @noa No it's nil. I added the observer in the `init method` of my AppController. Now I have it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and it works fine. Thank you! :)